# Pubnub and Multiple XHR requests

Tags: xmlhttprequest, pubnub

I created simple webpage with a pubnub (3.4) subscription, about every 5 minutes I see an XHR request to pubnub from my Chrome console.  Is this correct behavior? Thanks for any insight!

```
In doSubscribe 
XHR finished loading: "https://ps3.pubnub.com/time/0". pubnub-3.4.min.js:11
XHR finished loading: "https://ps2.pubnub.com/time/0". pubnub-3.4.min.js:11
XHR finished loading: "https://ps1.pubnub.com/subscribe/demo/xxxxx/0/0?uuid=fb81a2a0-3fdc-4be1-94b2-dd23ce0c4bcd". pubnub-3.4.min.js:11
XHR finished loading: "https://ps1.pubnub.com/subscribe/demo/xxxxx/0/13569794952114592?uuid=fb81a2a0-3fdc-4be1-94b2-dd23ce0c4bcd". pubnub-3.4.min.js:11
XHR finished loading: "https://ps1.pubnub.com/subscribe/demo/xxxxx/0/13569794952114592?uuid=fb81a2a0-3fdc-4be1-94b2-dd23ce0c4bcd". pubnub-3.4.min.js:11
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is expected as PubNub uses [HTTP Long-Polling](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide/realtime-web-technology-transport-mechanisms#http-long-polling) for communication between the client and server.

Comment: Phil you need to update your communication blog.  For example PubNub does not close connections, we keep open sockets open.  :-)

Comment: Are you saying you use http long polling with keep alive (if so, do you have a reference for browser keep-alive support?)? Or are you using Http streaming or WebSockets?

Comment: @PubNub Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

## ANSWER: PubNub and Multiple XHR requests

These 5 minute responses you show are PINGS from PubNub Cloud.  Yes this is expected and correct behavior.  Read more below to learn about how PubNub streams data to your client like Google Chrome.  Also see [What are the Blank Messages my Application Keeps Receiving](https://help.pubnub.com/entries/21119318-what-are-the-blank-messages-my-application-keeps-receiving) to learn a bit more.  Continue reading for the specifics:

## PubNub Socket Connections

PubNub JavaScript client for mobile and web browsers like Chrome (webkit) maintain a socket connection that will last for **one hour** and up to **24 hours** depending on the network traffic.  Connections are refreshed after **24 hours** and will automatically reconnect with reliable data deliverability (Catch-up Missed Messages).  This is because PubNub maintains a Cloud Queue for your clients which re-delivers any missed messages.

## PubNub Dropped Connection Catch-up

PubNub uses Cloud Queues to maintain messages in-memory until the data has been delivered to your client device like Google Chrome.  So if you drop your connection, you will still receive the data sent during the offline state and once the connection has been restored, you will receive your messages.

## PubNub XHR Pings and Requests

In your Chrome Dev Console you will see pings every **300 seconds** which is 5 minutes.  These pings are an [Application Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer) transport protocol that ensures the data stream is still active and alive.  This is helpful in states of internet loss and restoration.  This allows *better-than* TCP-KeepAlive connectivity and improved reliability.  During Data Transmission Cycle, the connection state is maintained as described in the previous section with connections laster up to 24 hours before they are recycled.